# Вывод абзацев yii через CHtml::encode()

Tags: yii

Есть проблема с выводом в yii. CHtml::encode($text) выводит все в одну строку. Если применить nl2br и выводить просто: echo nl2br($text), то все ОК. Но тогда пользователь сможет вводить теги. Если CHtml::encode(nl2br($text)) - логично, что выведет в одну строку, но с тегами.

Как решить проблему без лишнего парсинга?

Comment: CHtml::encode(nl2br($text)) - не логично, ибо CHtml::encode() замена htmlspecialchars() который как раз режет тэги)

Comment: ну я имел ввиду, что выведет текст с тегами в самом тексте, а не в html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то совсем туплю по ночам...

```
echo nl2br( CHtml::encode($text) );
```

И все ОК))